# ssh caches host names?

Tags: ssh, hostname

I changed a host address in /etc/hosts and it is definitely working because if I do `ping [hostname]` then the correct address is pinged.

However, when I run `ssh [hostname]` I get the OLD host address. So, apparently ssh is caching the hostname addresses somehow. How do I clear this cache so it will use the current host address, not the old one?

Comment: Do you have a configuration entry in your `.ssh/config` for the host in question?

Comment: @roaima That I do. You found the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in roaima's comment, it turns out that there were hardcoded IP addresses in the ssh config file (~/.ssh/config) that were overriding the /etc/hosts file entries.